# How place our own links in facebook wall message

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building a facebook app, in which I am writing user wall using face book graph api.

Now I would like to include more than 1 links in the message . Is it possible,how can I do it.

This is my code

```
$facebook->api('/'.$uid.'/feed', 'post', array(
            'message' => 'Dear friend, I have given '.$input['rate']." to the movie". $moviedetails['ftitle']. "from ReelReview",
            'name' => $moviedetails['ftitle'],
            'description' => $moviedetails['description'],
            'caption' => 'ReelReview - the best movie review app',
            'picture' => 'http://site.com/Movie.jpg',
            'link' => 'http://mysite.com'
        ));
```

Now I am trying to include some links in the message and description,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one 'link' per wall post , however you could include several links in your description. 
The difference is that the 'link' property will be the link that facebook scans for information, and displays images and so forth. 
The links in the description will look like in a normal message.